# Flyway - Cant run Multiple sql Scripts

Tags: flyway

My files - V3.2-alter.sql    and V3.2-3insert_fmcc.sql

If i am running flyway  - i get error ..

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:3.2.1:migrate (default) on project
>   SnapdealOPS: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found more than
>   one migration with version 3.2  Offenders:
>
> [ERROR] ->
>   /home/kartikeya/git/SnapdealOPS/MySQLDB/release-V3.2/V3.2-1alter.sql
>   (SQL) [ERROR] -> /home/kartikeya/git/SnapdealOPS/MySQLDB/release-
>
> V3.2/V3.2-3insert_fmcc.sql (SQL)

Cant i run multiple sql scripts for single version . Do i have to put all the queries in single file .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want two files, you need to give them two versions (like 3.2.0.0.1 and 3.2.0.0.2). That is how the order of application is defined.

Comment: But they all belong to our single release (version) 3.2 ... i mean logically it wouldnt make sense to have different versions based on file not on version

Comment: You need some mechanism to define the order of application. Flyway provides: order of lines within the file and numeric ordering of version numbers between files.